# Java containers: Can the same object be in more than one container at once?

Tags: java, containers

Let us say I have:

```
ArrayList l2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList();
MyClass c = new MyClass();
l1.add(c);
l2.add(c);
```

And I do:

```
System.out.println(l1.contains(l2.get(0)));
```

I get the answer "true"

Could someone please explain why the resulted answer and how (if possible ) the answer could change to "false"?

Comment: y not u try it and show us what will be the output..

Comment: You can read the doc for `contains` and `get`.

Comment: What do you see on the console ? Why are you even asking this question ?

Answer (score 3):

The output will be true. Because the object is in both Lists.
**Note**: At least if you followed the rules of `equals()` in your `MyClass` class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The same reference value can be in two containers.

In your example one `MyClass` instance named `c` is added to List(s) `l1` and `l2` and the output should be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
MyClass c
```

this is a *reference* to an object, not the object itself.

So when you add it to the container, you are adding a copy of the *reference* not a copy of the object, or the object itself.

You can have references to the same object in any number of containers, or data structures and all these references will point to the same object.